# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead when trying to make predictions

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

```
m = np.array([[1,5,3,6,10,20]])
c = np.array([[100,500,300,600,1000,2000]])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(m,c)
```

I get the error when trying to make the prediction.

```
model.predict([5])
```

If I add double brackets, it forces me to pass 6 inputs, but the idea is that it receives only one or as many as I want.

Comment: Why do you train a `model`, bit you predict from `modelo`? Is it a typo just here, or in your code, too? Please edit your post to clarify and remedy this.

Comment: Are you trying to predict `c` from `m`, or are you trying to make a linear model like `y = mx + c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trained the wrong model. You train 6 models, each with 6 features (and your dataset is only 1-point).

```
# should be this
m = np.array([[1,5,3,6,10,20]]).T
c = np.array([100,500,300,600,1000,2000])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(m,c)

modelo.predict([[5]])
# array([500])
```

Comment: thanks a lot,it didn't work this way modelo.predict([5]) I had to add double brackets.

Comment: I have seen a lot of theory, and the truth is that I have not understood your solution. Could you recommend a reading that will clarify these doubts? <3